# Trigger a segue by hitting Search on keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uistoryboard, segue

I have an app where I want a user to tap on a text field, type in their search query, and hit the keyboard's Return (or here, Search) button. Doing so should trigger a segue, and send some data in the `prepareForSegue` method to the next controller.

This method is currently being triggered by a UIButton, and it works fine, but I'd like the exact same thing to happen when hitting Search on the keyboard, so I can remove the button and streamline the process.

I've tried calling `[self prepareForSegue]` in the `textFieldShouldReturn` method (of the delegate) but it hasn't worked.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"DisplaySearchResults"]) {
        SearchResultsViewController *searchResultsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        searchResultsViewController.searchQuery = _searchQuery;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplaySearchResults" sender:self];
```

in textFieldShouldReturn.

prepareForSegue will be called automatically after performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: This will work, just make sure that the parent class is a delegate for that UITextField.

Comment: You can fire a push segue setup on the text field simply by hiding the keyboard. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837689/if-keyboard-is-not-dismissed-segueing-when-using-a-search-bar-changes-destinati