# If keyboard is not dismissed, segueing when using a search bar changes destination view controller layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UITableView` where I display a list of chat rooms. I'm also using a search bar to find an specific chat room. When a user taps into a cell, it segues to the chat room conversation, displaying the messages and a text box to send messages.

However, if I seach a chat room using the search bar, when I tap in any cell the segue is done but the layout of the chat room is wrong. The conversation view (custom `UITableView`) fills the whole screen and the text box (located at the bottom, just in top of a `TabBar`) doesn't appear.

Trying to solve this issue, I've discovered that I was able to segue correctly when searching if I dismissed the keyboard before tapping into any cell, so it seems that this is only happening when the keyboard is present.

I think I can solve this issue programatically dismissing the keyboard before segueing, but I'm also afraid that maybe I'm doing something wrong with the `UISearchBar`or the `UITableView`.

My target project is iOS 5.1 and I've reproduced this issue in an iPad 3 running 5.1, iPad 2 running 6.01 and iPhone simulators.

**EDIT**

This is the code I'm using to segue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.searchController.searchResultsTableView == tableView) {
        self.selectedItem = [self.filteredItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        self.selectedItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueChatRoom" sender:self];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; // This line solves the issue
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Custom title" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueChatRoom"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setItem:self.selectedItem];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code, on how you are segueing to the next view?

Comment: @PaulPeelen I've just added the segue code.

Comment: Your code looks correct, I seems that the sized (maybe even margin) of the conversation view might be incorrect? Could you possibly add a screenshot of the conversation view so I know I understand you correctly? In the conversation view, are you adding the tableview programatically and setting the frame to e.g. 320x480? (Stupid question, but worth asking).

Comment: What viewController are you sending the setItem to? Have you tried YourOtherViewController * YVC = (YourOtherViewController* )[segue destinationViewController]; [YVC setItem:self.selectedItem];

Answer (score 1):

As you already pointed out you need to resign the first responder (lower the keyboard). Your [self.view endEditing:YES]; is essentially doing this.

Comment: Do you have any link or references about this? I've solved the issue doing this, but I can't find any explanation about why is this needed.

Comment: One test would be to make the textView on your destination controller becomeFirstResponder during your prepareForSegue method. Resigning first responder prior to the end of a segue is not bad practice and makes for better animation transitions. Have you tried the code I posted as a comment? I'm curious how you are instantiating your destination view without explicitly doing so. "    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueChatRoom"]) {
        YourOtherViewController * YVC = (YourOtherViewController* )[segue destinationViewController]; [YVC setItem:self.selectedItem];
    }"